# Does a dryad's Tree Stride ability provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, opportunity-attack

> **Tree  Stride.** Once on her turn, the dryad can use 10 feet of her movement to step magically into one living tree within her reach and emerge from a second living tree within 60 feet of the first tree, appearing in an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the second tree. Both  trees must be large or bigger. (MM p.121)

It's obvious that the dryad will get out of reach of a melee assailant. **But is this considered a teleportation? Does this movement provoke opportunity attacks?** Keep in mind that this ability is not listed as an action.

Comment: Note that there is a Tree Stride spell that works almost identically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **tele|port.**
>
> VERB
>
> 1. (especially in science fiction) transport or be transported across space and distance instantly.
>      "who needs a flying carpet if you can teleport yourself and your belongings?"
>
> **teleportation**
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. noun form of teleport

**Yes**

The rules do not define "teleport" so its normal English definition applies.

If the dryad is within an opponents reach then by stepping into the tree they trigger an opportunity attack if they leave that reach because this is normal movement; a "step". The transfer from tree to tree is teleportation and would not trigger an opportunity attack.

Of course, normal opportunity attack criteria apply, if the dryad can't be seen or takes the Disengage action then no opportunity attack.

Answer (score 2):

## It Depends On What Else She's Doing and if She Has enough Movement Remaining

If she has taken an Action and then leaves someone's reach without using the Disengage action, she'll provoke an opportunity attack ([per Dale M's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/74004/22566)).

PHB p. 192. Disengage

> If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn't provoke
>   opportunity attacks for the rest of your turn.

Reviewing the Dryad description on MM Page p. 121, her Actions are listed as a Club (melee weapon attack) and a Fey Charm.  That tree stride looks to be a subset of her movement.(Not an action, not a bonus action).

*Therefore,* if she takes the Disengage action (rather than an attack or an attempt at Fey Charm) and then uses 10' of movement (providing she has that much movement left for that turn) she'd be able to avoid the Opportunity Attack and go through the trees.

Answer (score 2):

**YES** the Dryad does provoke an Opportunity Attack, given she has not used the Disengage action or any other ability that avoids triggering opportunity attacks.

You could argue that the Dryad teleports as part of entering the tree, that she is not there to hit and that teleportation does not provoke, or perhaps the tree is in the way. This would be an incorrect application of the rules to the order of events:

- the Dryad *moves*, using up 10' of her movement, into the space of a tree within her reach
- if this move would put her out of your reach this provokes an opportunity attack which *interrupts* her movement, it happens *before* she leaves your reach, i.e. before she teleports, before the tree could be in the way
- if you have your reaction available you can make an opportunity attack
- if she is still able to, after the results of the opportunity attack, the Dryad completes her move into the space of the tree
- the Dryad teleports

The important factors are: that the Dryad has to use some of her *move* (magical or not) to enter the tree, which if takes her out of your reach satisfies the requirements to trigger an opportunity attack; and that the opportunity attack interrupts and happens before she leaves your reach, i.e. *before* she enters the tree.

As the teleport part of this ability has her *appear* within 5' of the tree, she does **not** *move* out of the tree at the other end and so this does **not** provoke an opportunity attack. However any of her subsequent movement (remaining after subtracting the 10') is as normal.

As this ability is listed as using part of her movement she can use the disengage action first (obviously first because it covers movement during the *rest* of your turn) to avoid this consequence of her move into the tree, and any movement after she has re-appeared.

---

Opportunity Attack (PHB p. 195):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach.
>
> The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s movement, occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.
>
> You also don’t provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport

Tree Stride (MM p.121):

> Once on her turn, the dryad can use 10 feet of her movement to step magically into one living tree within her reach and emerge from a second living tree within 60 feet of the first tree, appearing in an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the second tree. Both trees must be large or bigger.

Disengage (PHB p.192):

> If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn't provoke opportunity attacks for the rest of your turn.